# How to launch the default Music Player in Windows10

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-10

[image: Windows10 Volum Panel]

How could I launch the default music player in Windows 10 from my WinForms application.
And how to get the play status (like the info in picture)?

Comment: maybe i can use SendKeys.Send("{SelectMedia}"); But it seems can not take effect

Answer (score 0):

You can launch the default music app by using the `Launcher` api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.System.Launcher) and pointing it to a music file (.mp3, .wav).

However, you can't control another UWP app or get info from it since UWP apps are sandboxed.

Windows, being the OS and host of the app, has access to everything the app is doing and so it can monitor it and get any data from it, this is why the Volume Control can display this info.

Edit: technically, an app playing music in background will have access to APIs that control that Volume Control display and using those APIs, the app can set the picture, track name, artist name, and so on.

Comment: I just launch the app, but not open a music file. I will read the doc, may be it support launch without specific file.

Comment: 2. If I could get the play status without track name, artist name...?

Comment: @lystormenvoy take a look at the `BackgroundMediaPlayer` class which has a method `IsMediaPlaying' that returns true if other media is playing on the device.
Take a look at the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Media.Playback.BackgroundMediaPlayer#methods_

Comment: hi, I found the api is for uwp, but I use in winform